# "Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript"

Tags: r, rstudio

implementando un código en R en el que planeo implementar distintos métodos de imputación, cargo el paquete NHANES y planeo crear una variable que recoja los missing data de hombres y mujeres por separado, obteniendo el error comentado en el nombre. Probé a pasar el valor de la columna a dicotómico para ver si con eso se solucionaba, pero sigue dando error. ¿Alguien sabe como resolverlo?
Este es el inicio donde me da el error:

```
library(NHANES)

df_nahn <- NHANES

nhanes <- df_nahn %>% 
  mutate(miss_phys_active = is.na(PhysActive))

library(tidyverse)
df_nahnes <- df_nahn %>% mutate(Gender = recode(Gender, "male" = "0", "female" = "1")) 


miss_phys_active_male <- df_nahnes %>% 
  filter(Gender == 0) %>% 
  pull(miss_phys_active)   # 0 es male
```

Comment: Hola Lancab, bienvenido/a. ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo mínimo reproducible del error? Sin los datos que permiten reproducir el error es prácticamente imposible ofrecer una respuesta. Por lo que pude explorar del error el problema es una confusión de nombres en el argumento de `pull()`. Al parecer `miss_phys_active` existe en el entorno global, pero no dentro del data.frame que pasa implícitamente como argumento `.data` con la tubería. Sin embargo sin los datos no podría ir más allá a buscar una solución.

Comment: Quizás te ayude verificar en el paso inmediatamente anterior al `pull` si existe una columna llamada `miss_phys_active` en el data.frame. Si no existe el problema está antes.

Comment: @mpaladino muchas gracias, y lamento no haberlo descrito bien. Adjunto el código previo, simplemente he leído un paquete ya existente llamado NHANES: install.packages("NHANES") library(NHANES) df_nahn <- NHANES
names(df_nahn) (lamento el formato en el que te contesto, esta plataforma es nueva para mí. Simplemente instalé el paquete, lo denominé df_nahn por comodidad y miré un poco su forma.). El término miss_phys_active no existe en el dataframe, lo creo yo tomando los valores faltantes usando is.na.

Comment: excelente, esto ayuda mucho. Edité tu pregunta para agregar el código que incluyes en este comentario. Si no está correcto sería muy importante que lo edites para que quede igual al script con el que estás trabajando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que encuentro es que en el objeto `df_nahnes` no está la columna `miss_phys_active` y por eso tienes un error. Entiendo que lo que quieres es obtener un vector lógico que sea `TRUE` cuando es NA `PhysActive` y `FALSE` cuando no y que incluya solamente a población masculina. Eso lo podrías hacer con

```
library(NHANES)
library(tidyverse)

df_nahn <- NHANES

df_nahn %>% 
  mutate(miss_phys_active = is.na(PhysActive)) %>% 
  mutate(Gender = recode(Gender, "male" = "0", "female" = "1")) %>% 
  filter(Gender == 0) %>% 
  pull(miss_phys_active)
```

## Respuesta larga: ¿por qué dos errores diferentes?

Lo extraño es que cuando reproduzco tu código también obtengo un error,pero es diferente: `Error: objeto 'miss_phys_active' no encontrado`. Estuve revisando como falla `pull()` para tratar de entenderlo. Probé con otros datos más simples y que conozco mejor y esto es lo que encontré:

```
#Produce Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
#mean es el nombre de una función que está en el entorno global

mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 6) %>% 
  pull(mean) 

#No hay problema, porque busca el nombre mean dentro del data.frame y lo encuentra
mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 6) %>% 
  mutate(mean = cyl) %>% 
  pull(mean) 

#Produce el error Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist.
#Al pasar el argumento como una cadena de caracteres ya no lo busca en el entorno global, al no encontrarlo localmente produce un error más razonable

mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 6) %>% 
  pull("mean") 

#Produce Error: objeto 'no_en_entorno' no encontrado
#No lo encuentra en el data.frame, no lo encuentra en el entorno global e indica que no hay ningún objeto asociado a ese nombre

mtcars %>% 
  filter(cyl == 6) %>%
  pull(no_en_entorno)
```

El problema que tienes es el de la respuesta corta del principio, el nombre de la columna que vas a extraer con `pull` debe estar en el data.frame. Sin embargo el error específico que emite depende de si hay un objeto con ese nombre en el entorno global (puede ser el nombre de una función) o no lo hay y también depende de como pasemos el argumento. La evaluación no estándar que utiliza `tidyverse` tiene sus ventajas, pero en algunos casos complica las cosas. Lo ideal sería que para el mismo problema (no encuentra la columna) tuvieramos el mismo error.

Comment: muchísimas gracias!! Donde vi este código aplicado a otro conjunto entiendo que tenía ciertas variables ya añadidas al entorno. Gracias al ejemplo que me ha mostrado he podido modificar el mío para que funcione :)